# VB.Net XML Getting Node from attribute then writing to that node

Tags: xml, vb.net

Basically I'm trying to read settings from a XML file but I have all the nodes the same name that I'm using so I have to assign them ID's but how do I go about getting the node from the attribute ID and writing to that node I have just found

Here is what I have:

```vb
Public Sub write_xml_file(ByVal path As String, ByVal nodePath As String, ByVal innerText As String)
    If IO.File.Exists(path) = True Then

        ' Load the XmlDocument.
        Dim xd As New XmlDocument()
        xd.Load(path)

        Dim node As XmlNodeList = xd.SelectNodes(nodePath)

        If node IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim nodeId As Integer = 0
            For Each childNode As XmlElement In node
                MessageBox.Show(get_node_count(node))
                If childNode("p").InnerText = "" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Found empty...")
                    Exit For
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Empty place not found, carry on looking...")
                    nodeId += 1
                    Continue For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        MessageBox.Show("Finished")
        ' Save the Xml.
        xd.Save(path)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Could not write to selected path: " + path)
    End If
End Sub
```

As you can see all I am doing is just getting the first node from the list without getting the node with attribute 1, 2, 3 etc. I just cant figure out how to get this and then use it to edit the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `xd.SelectNodes(nodePath)`, that `nodePath` argument can be any valid XPath.  XPath provides all sorts of flexibility.  In this case, you want to add a conditional clause which says you only want to select nodes by that name *where they also contain an attribute by a certain name which equal a certain value*.  Here's an example of how you can express a condition like that in XPath:

```vb
Dim node As XmlNodeList = xd.SelectNodes("/MyRoot/MyElement[@MyAttribute = 'MyValue']")
```

In the above example, the document object is going to look for a `MyRoot` element in the root of the XML document.  It's then going to find all of the `MyElement` elements which are direct children of that `MyRoot` element.  It's then going to filter them to only include ones which contain an attribute called `MyAttribute` which equals `MyValue`.  In other words:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MyRoot>
  <MyElement>Will not be selected</MyElement>
  <MyElement MyAttribute="Wrong">Will not be selected</MyElement>
  <MyElement MyAttribute="MyValue">Will be selected</MyElement>
  <MyElement MyAttribute="MyValue">Will be selected</MyElement>
</MyRoot>
```